React Native Xcode build error: React-Codegen Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
I created fresh projects on both React Native CLI and Expo, tried to get a build, I got this error in Xcode.

Background of this problem:
React Native (Expo) Xcode build error "Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 70."
